# Touch Conditional Loading with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, touch

I'm trying to conditionally load a .js file depending if isTouchDevice is true. And right after add a class to #slider that defines the type of slider that is displayed and the options required for each. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and I'm open to other suggestions on how to accomplish this.

**Update:** https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider 
http://swipejs.com/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function isTouchDevice() {
return (typeof(window.ontouchstart) != 'undefined') ? true : false;
};

if (isTouchDevice == true) {//Hook up Swipe

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "swipe.min.js",
      dataType: "script"
    }).done(function() { //Hook up Swipe
        $("#slider").addClass("swipe");
        var slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));
    });
};

else {//Hook up Flexslider

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "jquery.flexslider.js",
      dataType: "script"
    }).done(function() { //Hook up Flexslider
        $("#slider").addClass("flexslider");
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({directionNav: false});
};
});
```

HTML Markup:

```
<div id="slider">

     <ul class="slides">

         <li>
             <img src="images/loch-nevis.jpg" alt="" />
         </li>

         <li>
             <img src="images/snow.jpg" alt="" />
         </li>

         <li>
             <img src="images/iceland.jpg" alt="" />
         </li>

     </ul><!-- end slides -->

</div><!-- end slider -->
```

Comment: `if (isTouchDevice = true)` should be `if (isTouchDevice == true)`? By the way, this is the same as `if (isTouchDevice)`

Comment: My mistake that was a typo, not the issue at hand, already updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the jQuery getScript method?

```
if (isTouchDevice == true) {//Hook up Swipe
    $.getScript("swipe.min.js", 
        function() {
            $("#slider").addClass("flexslider");
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({directionNav: false })  // Removed errant ","
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: the $.getScript method just calls the $.ajax method in jquery.

Comment: It is more concise for this purpose.

Comment: Ok it might be but still isn't solving my issue :/

Comment: Have you tried using a .fail function? Is "swipe.min.js" in your root folder when the call is made?

Comment: I have a separate whatever.js file with my codes that I refer to just before </body>. It's in a "javascripts" folder together with all of the .js files. The .js files aren't in the same folder as the index.html

Answer (score 0):

if isTouchDevice is working properly, you could try lab.js or yepnope

lab.js example:

```
if (isTouchDevice===true) {
  $LAB
    .script('swipe.min.js')
    .wait(function() {
      // do some stuff
    })
}
```

yepnope: (could be wrong on this, have never really used yepnope)

```
yepnope({
  test:isTouchDevice,
  yep:'swipe.min.js',
  callback: function (testResult,key) {
    // do some stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't yepnope work hand in hand with Modernizr? I've never used either of the suggestions you proposed either. But I'll give it a try.

Comment: yeah, modernizr is worked into yepnope. apparently they do have a Modernizr.touch test, so that's an easy fix.